# ActionScript 3.0 Getting the index [CLICK event] of a loaded movie Clip image

Tags: actionscript-3, scripting, adobe, flash-cs5

I am loading a set of thumbnail images from an array [hard coded] into a movieclip symbol on the stage. I have two arrays with the thumbnail and the full size image having the same index number. In many examples, "event.currentTarget.contentLoaderInfo.url" returns the full path to the image selected. i just want the index number.

Adobe does not make is easy to figure out what other properties are available to me from the contentLoaderInfo. Is 'SelectedIndex' or something like that available?

Where does an inspiring AS programmer find the contentLoaderInfo properties and or methods available? Is url the only thing that us usable here?

Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

```
var thumbnails:Array = ["tn_2010OpenHouse_00.jpg","tn_2010OpenHouse_01.jpg"];
var images:Array = ["2010OpenHouse_00.jpg","2010OpenHouse_01.jpg"];
var thumbX:Number = 10;
var thumbY:Number = 623;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + images[0]));
addChild(loader);
loadThumbs();

function loadThumbs():void
{
    var thumbLoader:Loader;
    var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
    container.width =  100;
    addChild(container);

    container.buttonMode = true;
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++)
    {
        thumbLoader = new Loader();
        thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + thumbnails[i])); 
        thumbLoader.x = thumbX; 
        thumbLoader.y = thumbY;
        thumbX +=  100;
        container.addChild(thumbLoader);
        thumbLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, thumbClicked);
        container.width +=  100;
        addChild(thumbLoader);
    }
    stop();
}

function thumbClicked(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
         //weltraumpirat's example 
    var index:int = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.target.contentLoaderInfo.url );
    trace("Index= "+ index);
         //trying a different approach as well 
    index = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.currentTarget.contentLoaderInfo.url );
    trace("Index= "+ index);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + images[index]));
}
```

Output:
Index= -1
Index= -1
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

The `contentLoaderInfo` property returns a `LoaderInfo` class. You can view its properties here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html

Comment: Lets see, in my question, I am asking about the "contentLoaderInfo" and what other properties [methods] are available besides 'url', and where I can find this information. [Adobe's 'intellisense' is only slightly useful, and only displays when it wants to]. 

Am I to asume that 'contentLoaderInfo' = LoaderInfo?I guess I should asume that 'contentLoaderInfo' only has one property 'url'.

Comment: Verbatim from Adobe: The `contentLoaderInfo` property is always available for any `Loader` object. For a `Loader` object that has not called the `load()` or `loadBytes()` method, or that has not sufficiently loaded, attempting to access many of the properties of the `contentLoaderInfo` property throws an error. The `contentLoaderInfo` property of a `Loader` object provides information about the content that the `Loader` object is loading, whereas the `loaderInfo` property of a `DisplayObject` provides information about the root SWF file for that display object.

Comment: In short, `stage.loaderInfo` and `loader.contentLoaderInfo` both utilize the `LoaderInfo` object (meaning the same properties), but provide different values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This post can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array.indexOf()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#indexOf%28%29) to return an object's index.  Since I don't know the rest of your code, here's an approximate example:

```
function thumbClicked (ev:MouseEvent) : void {

    var index:int = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.target.contentLoaderInfo.url );
    loader.load ( new URLRequest (fullSizeImages[index]) ) ;
}
```

**Edit**:

Since I didn't know the exact code you were using, I assumed you store the entire path to the picture in your array.  In your code, you prepend "images/", so the code should be:

```
function thumbClicked (ev:MouseEvent) : void {

    var index:int = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.target.contentLoaderInfo.url.substring (7)); 
    // 7 is the length of "images/", so substring returns only the filename part.

    loader.load ( new URLRequest (fullSizeImages[index]) ) ;
}
```

Comment: I am successfully loading the first full sixe image, and all the thumbnails on the stage. Here is my current code with your addition:function thumbClicked(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
 var index:int = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.target.contentLoaderInfo.url );
 trace("Index= "+ index);
 index = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.currentTarget.contentLoaderInfo.url );
 trace("Index= "+ index);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + images[index]));
}

Comment: function thumbClicked(ev:MouseEvent):void { var index:int = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.target.contentLoaderInfo.url ); trace("Index= "+ index); index = thumbnails.indexOf ( ev.currentTarget.contentLoaderInfo.url ); trace("Index= "+ index); loader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + images[index])); } the output is as follows:Index= -1
Index= -1
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.Once the thumbnail is loaded, how is it referenced on the stage?

Comment: Sorry, this my first attempt at getting a question answered here. Thanks for your help. This post can be deleted.

Comment: You can delete the comments yourself ;)